# Guacamole ssh login details not correct

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, guacamole

So in a previous question I was trying to log into localhost's shell via guacamole. The solution was to enable password authentication for localhost connections in the sshd config.

So I looked at the guacamole settings more closely and noticed this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJomQ.png

I know of the `hostname`, with it being the server's ip. Then port is just what I enabled in `sshd` config. Private key with passphrase I can also give by copying over the `cat` of my `id_ed25519` file and paste in the corresponding passphrase.

What I don't get is how I fill in the public key section. I use to only ssh to machines from my terminal. And a simple ssh oonfig pointing to the key file would work. What do I need to fill in there? A plain `cat` of my associated `id_ed25519.pub` didn't seem to work.

EDIT:

So far I tried to leave the passphrase for the key file blank. And then I am prompted to enter one. After which I am immediately kicked out with log in failed. When I use a key without a passphrase I am still asked for one, pressing enter without passphrase entered also errors me out.

Answer (score 0):

As close as I can determine, the ssh logon in guacamole does not work. I tested an RSA keypair both 2048 and 4096, both of which worked via an ssh terminal to the remote system.  In guacamole, you would think that you would need to configure the authentication initially to have username, password and the private key in guacamole.

The reasoning behind this is that you would have to initially provide your username/password to get the private key added into the remote system.  Then you would perform an initial connection which you would expect loads the key.  At that point, I would think that you go back into your authentication profile for that system and delete the password and private key leaving only the username.  I would think this would be simulating a "ssh username@IP" and the user should be logged in.  As it stands, this does not work even though from a standard terminal, the user is authorized.

Comment: So even if I enable the password authentication the first time, after having a private key added, I should be able to log in with just the user name and private key. I don't understand what you mean when you said "At that point, I would think that you go back into your authentication profile for that system and delete the password and private key" Which will leave me with no way to authenticate. Since plain password is disabled.